# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE vs. SQL file

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

Every day we load around 6GB of CSV files into MySQL using:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file$i.csv' INTO TABLE tableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

We have 6 files that goes through this process, so it takes some time. Since we generate these files ourselves, we're in control of what format it gets outputted as.

Originally we chose CSV because this was a smaller process and we needed the data to be moved around and easily read by a non-developer. Now however, it's not so much of an issue since the loading time is so dramatic, we're now talking hours.

Is it quicker to output each row as an `INSERT` query into a single file and execute that or is CSV still quicker?

We're using the InnoDB storage engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use MyISAM tables, try ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE KEYS; before loading the data and ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE KEYS; after data import is done. This will greatly reduce your time taken for huge data.

Load data is faster than separate insert statement for each row.

Comment: I should mention that we're using `INNODB`.

Comment: Can you post following values of your database?

innodb_buffer_pool_size

innodb_log_file_size

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit



Also let us know your hardware configuration (especially RAM).

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size=26G`, `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` and the hardware is: 32GB RAM, 8 CPU (4 x 2).

Comment: Well, in that case, breaking those files into smaller chunks should help. InnoDB is slower in loading huge files through LOAD DATA.
Have a look at this
[link]http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/03/how-to-load-large-files-safely-into-innodb-with-load-data-infile/[/link]

Comment: So would it be faster for MySQL to process SQL files or CSV?

Comment: Plus, each individual file is around 500MB each.

Comment: Still it will be CSV that would be faster, because, in case of SQL statement file, it has to read each and every statement and process it one by one. While, in case of CSV file, it bulk loads the data and then commits.

Comment: Perfect - that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!